# await does not return to caller as expected using StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync()

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

Trying to understand streams and `async/await`. If I undertand correctly `await` returns execution to the caller so I expected the result of the code below to be:

```
before calling async ReadToEnd
after the call to ReadToEnd
before calling async ReadToEnd
after the call to ReadToEnd
```

But insted it is

```
before calling async ReadToEnd
after the call to ReadToEnd
before calling async ReadToEnd
after await in ReadToEnd. streamReader.BaseStream.GetType(): System.IO.MemoryStream
after the call to ReadToEnd
```

It seems that using a `StreamReader` with a `FileStream` underneath really returns to the caller when calling  `StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync()`, but it does not work when using a `StreamReader` with a `MemoryStream` underneath.

Trying to understand what is going on I've read the .NET source code and came to the conculssion that calling `StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync()` with a `MemoryStream` underneath eventually calls `ReadAsync()` ([source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs,2142088b3533a169,references)) on the BaseStream. In case of a `MemoryStream` the `ReadAsync()` is just not really a asynhnornous method and thus does not return to the caller.

Is my understanding correct?

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var longString = new string(Enumerable.Repeat('x', 100000000).ToArray());
        File.WriteAllText("bigFile.txt", longString, Encoding.UTF32);

        StreamReader fileStreamReader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"bigFile.txt"));
        Console.WriteLine("before calling async ReadToEnd");
        var task = ReadToEnd(fileStreamReader);
        Console.WriteLine("after the call to ReadToEnd");

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(longString);
        StreamReader memoryStreamReader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(bytes));
        Console.WriteLine("before calling async ReadToEnd");
        var task2 = ReadToEnd(memoryStreamReader);
        Console.WriteLine("after the call to ReadToEnd");

        fileStreamReader.Dispose();
        memoryStreamReader.Dispose();
    }

    static async Task ReadToEnd(StreamReader streamReader)
    {
        string allText = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("after await in ReadToEnd. streamReader.BaseStream.GetType(): " + streamReader.BaseStream.GetType());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it does, but MemoryStream is fast enough to immediately return. Hence, you see the extra Console.WriteLine appearing before the one you expected. Add a Sleep inbetween the await and Console.WriteLine and see what happens...

Comment: @AroglDarthu it isn't actually a question of "fast enough" - it simply *isn't async*; a method can be any of: slow and sync, slow and async, fast and sync, fast and async. Fast vs slow is moot - it is only the sync vs async that matters (within reason; obviously if it is async and fast enough to beat a `ret` instruction, then... well, maybe; but that's such an edge case that it doesn't matter)

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks for the insight.

Comment: @inwenis: You may find my [async intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful. In summary, `await` first checks to see whether its operation is complete, and if it is, then it continues executing *synchronously*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`await` *only* returns execution to the caller if the thing being awaited *did not complete synchronously*. Yes, `async` methods can complete synchronously if they choose, either because:

- they know the answer already (cached results, buffered data, known failure states, etc)
- they do not *have* a suitable asynchronous downstream operation to perform *at all*

`MemoryStream` is *always* synchronous, so it always does this.

`FileStream`, by contrast, *may or may not* complete synchronously, depending on what data is available in buffers, etc.

The decision as to whether to go back to the caller is driven by `GetAwaiter().IsCompleted`, which (for `Task`) comes down to `.IsCompleted`.

Answer (score 2):

In the first part of your code you are creating `StreamReader` from `File`. When you call `streamReader.ReadToEndAsync()` the file must be read first to memory from the hard drive before it contents can be returned which is done asynchronously.

In the second part of your code you are creating `StreamReader` from `MemoryStream` which was built from `bytes` that have been already loaded in memory of the application. In this case the `streamReader.ReadToEndAsync()` returns the contents immediately as the data is in memory and can be fetched right away.